# interface between two modules zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, module, zend-framework2, modularization, modular-design

is there a way to create interfaces between 2 modules so that they can interact with one another?
im working on zend framework2.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: for example in  mvcExpress framework you can send messages like
sendMessage("messageType", new ModuleCommunicationParams("Test params"));

is this possible in zend?

Comment: And what does that do? You can call methods on classes from other modules in ZF2, so you should be able to create classes to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 2 offers a service manager. It allows you to register a specific service into the manager where other objects could use these services. Just for the sake of an example, you have a Blog module and a Twitter module. When you post a new blog post, you send a tweet using the Twitter module.

Say you have a Twitter service class which has the following interface:

```php
namespace TwitterModule\Service;

interface TwitterServiceInterface
{
    public function tweet($text);
}

class TwitterService implements TwitterServiceInterface
{
    // implementation
}
```

Now you can register this service inside the `module.config.php` of the Twitter module:

```php
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokable' => array(
        'TwitterService' => 'TwitterModule\Service\TwitterService'
    ),
),
```

By this, **any** module could "ask" the service manager for the "TwitterService" and the service manager will return an instance of the `TwitterModule\Service\TwitterService`.

So, in your blog module:

```php
class BlogService
{
    public function store(array $data)
    {
        // create a $post, store it into DB

        // $sm is an instance of Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager
        $twitter = $sm->get('TwitterService');
        $tweet   = sprintf('Blogged: %s', $post->getTitle());
        $twitter->tweet($tweet);
    }
}
```

The example might not be the best (you don't want a coupling like this, you'd prefer to solve it via events, you'd use proper dependency injection) but it just shows how instances could be shared between modules.